# How to show the SplashScreen while the MainActivity is running

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a small Android Game and I want to show a Splash screen before each Level and after a Game Over.
Most tutorials I found only show Splash Screen implementations that run before the MainActivity is run.

In my case I would need to "run" the Splash Screen while the MainActivity is running. How can I achieve this?

I've already created a `SplashActivity` class that extends AppCompatActivity according to a Tutorial, but I don't think it is right for my Problem.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

The activity has the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.androidcodefinder.splashscreendemo.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:src="@mipmap/splash"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the `MainActivity` class I start a `GamePanel extends SurfaceView` that then starts a GameLoop.

```
@Override
public void run () {
    Canvas canvas;

    while (!this.exit) {
        canvas = null;

        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

            playAnimation(R.drawable.splash_gameover, R.anim.viewanimation);

            synchronized (this.surfaceHolder) {
                this.gamePanel.update();
                this.gamePanel.render(canvas, lag);
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                this.surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

at anywhere you want in `MainActivity` to bring up the `SplashActivity`. However, you probably don't want the `SplashActivity` to create another new `MainActivtiy`. You can pass some message through `Intent` to tell the `SplashActivtiy` what to do.

In `MainActivity`

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
i.putExtra("START_NEW_MAIN",false)
startActivity(i);
```

In `SplashActivity`

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final boolean startNewMain = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("START_NEW_MAIN",true)
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                if(startNewMain)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                finish();

            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

You can even completely remove the part that start `MainActivity` in `SplashActivity` if `SplashActivity` is not your app's entry point. Simply:

In `MainActivity`

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

In `SplashActivity`

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your fast reply.
I'd like to call the SplashScreen from my `GameThread` class, but there I don't have access to MainActivity.this and also not to startActivity(i);

I can get a Context from my PanelClass (Context from the SurfaceView).

Comment: `startActivtiy()` is a member of `Context` class. As long as you got a reference to the Context, you can always call `context.startActivity(new Intent(context,SplashActivity.class))`

Comment: I put the following lines now:


        Intent i = new Intent(gamePanel.getContext(), SplashActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("START_NEW_MAIN", false);
        gamePanel.getContext().startActivity(i);

But now I get stuck in a "gray screen", probably the default background for activity splash

Comment: You have to create an xml layout file for the splash screen and call for example `setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);` within `onCreate` of `SplashActivity`, just like other activity does.

Comment: I'm sorry for so many questions.. I created a activiy_splash.xml where i define a constraint layout with an image (in the preview of android studio it shows how i expect it, just the picture in the middle).
I then added under the `super.OnCreate(...)` the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);`
But I'm still stuck with the grey background, that doesn't go away after 5 seconds like i expected. Due to the 5000 in the `postDelayed(..)` call.

Answer (score 0):

In my android game [Anagram](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sebpo.anagram&hl=en) it is working fine, I used below code , U can check it out-

I created a xml like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#fff"
tools:context=".SplashScreen">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@drawable/splash" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Where @drawable/splash would be your desired background which U want to show

And below is SplashScreen code

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    }

}
```